# i try to make a navigator to sign in page in flutter, but thet say it doesn't have a constant constructor

Tags: flutter

```
class _SplashpageState extends State<Splashpage> {
  @override
  void initState() {

Timer(Duration(seconds: 3),
() => const Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in'),
);
super.initState();
}
```

I already see some tutorials on youtube, but it didn't work, please give some tips how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `const` which is in front of `const Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in'),`

```dart
class _SplashpageState extends State<Splashpage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in'),
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

`Navigator.pushNamed` is a static method, not a constructor (and therefore, not a const constructor) so it doesn't make sense to use `const` there.